# how to connect mySQL with jbpm 7.8.0

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, jbpm

I am trying to connect MySQL 8.0.11 database with jBPM 7.8.0. I have performed all steps provided in official jBPM documentation (https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.8.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_using_your_own_database_with_the_jbpm_installer)  but workflow engine jBPM is unable to connect. Please help me in this regard. i have performed following steps;
1. Disable H2 default database and enable MySQL database in build.properties
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBEjV.png)

2. db/jbpm-persistence-JPA2.xml :
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqtjb.png)
3. standalone-full-wildfly-{version}.xml :
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPu7I.png)
4. adding mysql-connector-java-5.1.18_module.xml in db folder. 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0KtK.png)
   ....

Execute following commands;

- ant stop.demo
- ant clean.demo
- ant install.demo
- ant start.demo

Comment: What issue you are facing ? any exception logged while starting server instance ?

Comment: @Abhijit ! I am facing following error in server.log file even i have changed default data source in standalone.xml file ;;;ERROR [WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jbpm-console.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.jbpm-console.jbpm-console.DefaultDataSource is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS]"]